# Running PHP under ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net

ASP.NET web server can allows  to deploy PHP code, even full applications like phpBB. is it possible? please guide me

by googling i found this

check this link

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=F8079

and in the time of running the PersonalWebSite projet getting error

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
and other projet is not oppening

Answer (score 1):

IIS will run PHP just fine alongside ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

If by "asp.net web server" you mean Microsoft IIS, then yes, you can install PHP engine as CGI (or FastCGI in IIS7) or even as an ISAPI filter and run any PHP app.